# Performance of TreeViewer.expandAll method

Tags: java, performance, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my application, an action is to expand all elements of a certain tree.

each time I execute this action, it takes longer time than before.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
getTreeViewer().expandAll();
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
System.out.println("expandAll time :  " + endTime );
```

and this is a sample from the output.

expandAll time : 200
expandAll time : 800
expandAll time : 1800
expandAll time : 3200

-- This slowdown my plugin so much. Is this an issue with the method ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a filter in place?  Filters and other TreeViewer collaborators are invoked on expand actions.  Also check the implementation of the LabelProvider to see if there's anything that could take a while when calculating the text label and image for each of the newly displayed tree items.

Comment: Yes, I have a filter. but even when I disable it, I go the same performance.
I use eclipse EMF generated providers for the label and content provider

Comment: OK. How many tree items are being exposed and how expensive is the getChildren() method on the ContentProvider?

Comment: about 100 item.

getChildren takes some milliseconds.
ex:
    
    getChildren takes 7 ms when expandAll takes: 1926 ms

Comment: You could also take a look at the getInput() method that is called by getRoot() in expandAll().

Comment: getInput also takes no time compared to createchildren in expandAll